# photos of people you follow instagram api

Tags: api, instagram

How can I get a feed of photos/videos from people I follow from the Instagram API? This seems like a pretty basic API feed that it appears to be missing. I see where I can get a list of the people I am following, but them am I supposed to make separate API calls for each of those user feeds and aggregate all of those together?

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows

I'm wondering how a service like http://web.stagram.com/ does something like this. I'm assuming aggregation, but perhaps I am missing something in the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The /user/self/feed endpoint returns all videos and photos of the user associated with the given access token. See here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed

This is an example of using this endpoint: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=969629.f59def8.24f8add8d4d7475397ab09b361299665

Comment: Thanks, confusing docs. I thought that one was "the authenticated user's own photos".

Comment: This is no longer a valid solution - that endpoint has been deprecated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888658/instagram-users-self-feed-404-errorcode

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API does not support what you are attempting. You would need aggregate these yourself. Not sure if webstagram has special access or has to work around this as well.