# Instagram users/self/feed 404 errorcode

Tags: instagram

I am trying to get myself mediafeeds information with the following API (using JInstagram library):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token={valid access_token}
```

The response code is 404. I am not sure what I'm missing since the access_token is valid, the API is listed in the [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) library, but it can't be found on the develop website.

I see there is a 404 error in this site for feeds to, but it are not same API.

Comment: PS. my client is int sandbox mode ,  is this because feed message is restricted?

Comment: seems that these api going to be deprecated

Answer (score 4):

Instagram changed their policy and also deprecated some APIs. Check the below link.

[https://instagram.com/developer/changelog/](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN)

**Old API**

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token={valid access_token}

**Use the below API instead of the above one**

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Comment: It's not the replacement. `/meda/recent` gives recent content you posted, not people you follow.

Comment: There is no replacement. Self/feed is permanently deprecated with no replacement because they didn't want 3rd party apps to have access to it.

Comment: Perhaps you can roll your own though by querying `/users/self/follows` then hitting `/users/user-id/media/recent` for each user. You'd probably need to cache the responses in your DB and run it all via some jobs. You'd probably hit your API limits though and Instagram might not be too keen.